# why I get undefined from the http service?

Tags: angularjs

I create $http service and using $q.

Here is my $http service:

```
function dashboardService($http, $log, $q, config) {

    var service = {
        getClientId: getClientIDByLayout,
    };

    return service;

    function getClientIDByLayout(layoutId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/ClientLayoutMercator?layoutId=" + layoutId).then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result.data);
        }, function (result) {
            deferred.reject(result);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }  
}
```

And here is how I call service above inside controller:

```
  dashboardService.getClientId(layoutId).then(function (data) {
      var t = data;//undifined
   });
```

But result I get in this row `var t = data` is `undefined`.

Any idea why I get undefined from the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have two return statement inside your `getClientIDByLayout` function and both are returning `promise` itself. As I can see with your current implementation your're creating new `promise` & managing rejection / resolve manually. But the problem is the 1st return statement (`return $http.get(`) is making other return statement(`return deferred.promise`) redundant. Hence 1st promise returned to subscription from controller. Eventually `$http.get` doesn't return anything so you get `undefined` in successCallback of then.

You can easily fix this issue by removing 1st return statement as shown below.

```
function getClientIDByLayout(layoutId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //removed `return` from below code.
    $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/ClientLayoutMercator?layoutId=" + layoutId).then(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result.data);
    }, function (result) {
        deferred.reject(result);
    });
    //custom promise should get return 
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

---

Ideally creating promise overhead considered as antipattern, rather you can utilize the promise returned by `$http.get`. Just return a data from its success callback to chain the promise.

**Code**

```
function getClientIDByLayout(layoutId) {
    ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶q̶.̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶
    return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/ClientLayoutMercator?layoutId=" + layoutId)
      .then(function (result) {
         //returning data from promise, it will provide it to subsequent `.then`
         return result.data;
      }, function (error) {
         ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ $q.reject(error);
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$q.defer`, simply [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) or [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) to the handler functions in the `.then` method:

```
function dashboardService($http, $log, ̶$̶q̶,̶ config) {

    var service = {
        getClientId: getClientIDByLayout,
    };

    return service;

    function getClientIDByLayout(layoutId) {
         ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶q̶.̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/ClientLayoutMercator?layoutId=" + layoutId).then(function (result) {
            ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶.̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶(̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶;̶ 
            return result.data;
        }, function (result) {
            ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶.̶r̶e̶j̶e̶c̶t̶(̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶)̶;̶ 
            throw result;
        });

        ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶r̶e̶d̶.̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶;̶
    }  
}
```

The `.then` method returns a **new promise** which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback` or `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)).<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)</sup>

By **erroneously** returning a promise with a `then` method that contained functions that **lacked [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) or [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) statements** the service was  returning a promise that resolved as `undefined`.

For more information, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).